# Scipy and scikit-learn no module named 'scipy.stats._qmc_cy'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to run a script in Python. I've installed numpy, scipy, scikit-learn etc. Every time I try to run the script, I get the error:

> line 35, in  from ._qmc_cy import (ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'scipy.stats._qmc_cy'

The beginning of my code is:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats
```

I know that the import scipy and import scipy.stats lines aren't necessary, but I included them just in case. As you can likely tell, I'm a bit new to all this. I have more experience writing code than dealing with these kind of installation and package issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've made multiple virtual environments and redownloaded the packages. I've updated everything.

I'm running `Python 3.11.4`, `numpy 1.25.1`, `scikit-learn 1.3.0`, `scipy 1.11.1`.

Comment: Do you have a more complete stack trace?

Comment: Those imports work for me on macOS (Python 3.10.11)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and just was able to solve it, hope it helps you.

Per my understanding, you might need to install the latest version of the library by doing: pip install scipy==1.9.2 (1.9.2 is the latest version as of now).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).